# How to Mock a store with global variable

Tags: vue.js, mocha.js, vuex

I have a file that I'm using to store a global variable that gets changed by 'login' or 'logout' functions. I want to write a unit test that has the value of 'isLoggedIn' set to true or false, then checks for expected behaviour. I can't figure out what I need to do to be able to use the value, this is my file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    loggedIn: false,
  },
  mutations: {
    login(state) {
      state.loggedIn = true;
    },
    logout(state) {
      state.loggedIn = false;
      state.userID = null;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    login({ commit }) {
      commit('login');
    },
    logout({ commit }) {
      commit('logout');
    },
  },
  getters: {
    isLoggedIn: (state) => state.loggedIn,
  },
});
```

And this is the test I'm trying to create:

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Home from '@/views/images.vue';

describe('Images.vue', () => {
  it('shows that you are logged in', () => {
    const welcome_text = 'You are logged in.';
    this.$store.dispatch('login');
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Home, {});
    expect(wrapper.text()).to.include(welcome_text);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your getter method isn't returning anything.

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#property-style-access

Once you change your getter to:

```
  getters: {
    isLoggedIn: (state) => return state.loggedIn,
  },
```

You should be able to retrieve this value using:

```
  this.$store.getters.isLoggedIn
```